# Why do my fetch request causes an infinite error loop in ReactJs using React Toast Notifications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, fetch, toast

I want to get a toast notification every time I catch an error in the fetch function.I am using a loop inside a component before the return to fetch data about different cities with accuweather api.


This is my handle errors function:

```
export const handleErrors = (response) => {
if (!response.ok) {
    return Promise.reject(response.statusText);
}
return response;}
```

This is my component that fetches the data:

```
import { useToasts } from 'react-toast-notifications';
import handleErrors from '../../handleErrors.js';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
favorites:state.favorites.favorites})

export const Favorites = (props) => {

const { addToast } = useToasts();
let data = null;

props.favorites.map((city,i) => {
fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/${city.CityKey}?apikey=${apiKey}`)
 .then(handleErrors)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(res => {data = [...data,res[0]];console.log(data)})
 .catch(error => addToast(error.message, { appearance: 'error' }))
});

return(
  <div>
    {data === null ? null : data.map((city,i => {
      return(<FavoriteTile
              city={city}
              key={i}/>
            )
  </div>
)
}
```

Now when trying to load the component page Im getting infinite toast errors and the page crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using functional components just wrap your fetch function with useEffect.

What's happening now is every-time you fetch something from that api your toast is updating hence component is being rerendered and calling fetch again in an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.favorites.map((city,i) => {
    fetch(`http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/${city.CityKey}? 
    apikey=${apiKey}`)
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => {data = [...data,res[0]];console.log(data)})
    .catch(error => addToast(error.message, { appearance: 'error' }))
  });
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

Where do you run your "fetch code"? I believe it should be somewhere inside `useEffect` (`componentDidMount`) otherwise it's being run all the time when the component re-renders.

Comment: Thanks! I also had a similar problem (fetch was run infinite amount of times if response is not ok, i.e. when I deliberately distorted the url, – despite a catch block in my async function in which no hook was applied). But when I moved my piece of code in which fetching is done inside the useEffect callback, the problem was gone.